# FolderShare (Windows Live Sync) for Ubuntu

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, sync, windows-live-sync

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Keeping folders synced between several machines](https://superuser.com/questions/349/keeping-folders-synced-between-several-machines)
>   [File syncing across multiple operating systems](https://superuser.com/questions/91001/file-syncing-across-multiple-operating-systems)

Is there something like FolderShare that I can run on my Windows and Ubuntu machines? I believe FolderShare had Mac and Linux clients before it was acquired by Microsoft but it seems to be gone now.

**PS: I'm not interested in online backup services, just something that can keep specific folders synced between two or more computers without storing the file(s) in the server (P2P like).**

Accessing the shared folders via an online interface (like what FolderShare used to do) is a plus.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "without storing the file(s) in the server."  Can you clarify?

Comment: @jonfhancock: Know what Windows Live Mesh / Dropbox is? That's what I don't want.

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/349/keeping-folders-synced-between-several-machines ... or http://superuser.com/questions/79744/alternatives-to-microsoft-live-mesh-and-microsoft-live-sync ... or http://superuser.com/questions/91001/file-syncing-across-multiple-operating-systems

Comment: @~quack: SU is becoming pretty much useless by the day, except from the "File syncing across multiple operating systems" question all are Windows only.

Comment: @~quack: powerfolder.com - there ya go, how is that for a "exact duplicate"?

Comment: http://www.ifolder.com/

Comment: @Alix:  I suggest you update your original question with all this expanded information you are looking for.  The more detailed and specific your questions are, the less likely they will look like duplicates of many SU questions.  I will re open this question if you feel it is not a duplicate and you update your question accordingly. Tell us everything you have tried and why you don't like it so people do not suggest those and get to solutions you are really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I use Dropbox for this purpose.  If you want to sync folders outside your "My Dropbox" folder, there is some coaxing required though.

http://dropbox.com

http://lifehacker.com/5154698/sync-files-and-folders-outside-your-my-dropbox-folder

Answer (score 0):

Try [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/):

> Unison is a file-synchronization tool for Unix and Windows. It allows
>   two replicas of a collection of files and directories to be stored on
>   different hosts (or different disks on the same host), modified
>   separately, and then brought up to date by propagating the changes in
>   each replica to the other.